# Create an engagement table relative to signup date

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a SQL query which will tell me what percentage of users were engaged on each day after signing up for an account. In the output table, *"percent of users engaged on this day"* refers not to a particular day, but to relative days since they signed up (i.e. their "first day" of having an account, regardless of calendar date).

So if I have three users and they all use the app for the first two days and then stop, the output would be 100% for days 1 and 2, and 0% for as many days it has been since the first user signed up. Day 1 is the day they signed up, so this day should always be 100% (their signup will show in the engagement table). I believe the query will start as follows, but I do not know how to calculate the number of people engaged on their Nth day (numerator), in addition to the total number of people who have been signed up at least N days (denominator).

```
SELECT date - signup_date as days_since_signup
FROM Users u
JOIN Engagement e
ON u.user_id=e.user_id
…
```

Users Table

| user_id | signup_date |
| --- | --- |
| 43 | 4/26/2021 |
| 76 | 4/29/2021 |
| 77 | 5/2/2021 |
| … |  |

Engagement table

| user_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 43 | 5/2/2021 |
| 43 | 5/3/2021 |
| 76 | 5/2/2021 |
| … |  |

Desired output:

| Day since signup | percent of users engaged on this day |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 95 |
| 3 | 93 |
| … |  |

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT days_since_signup, 
MAX(a.num_users)/COUNT(1) as pct_users
FROM ( SELECT date - signup_date as days_since_signup,
COUNT(1) as num_users
FROM Users u
JOIN Engagement e
ON u.user_id=e.user_id
GROUP BY days_since_signup
) a, 
Users u
WHERE today - u.signup_date >= days_since_signup
GROUP BY days_since_signup
```